# jQuery Validation - max method with decimal values

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using version 1.11.1 of [the library](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) I'm noticing that if I use something like

```
<input data-rule-max="8" />
```

it will correctly fail the validation when I enter a value of `10`.

However, if I have something like

```
<input data-rule-max="8.00" />
```

and I enter `10` it doesn't invalidate the field.  If I enter `9` it marks it as invalid, though.

When I debug, I can see that the max rule is receiving string values to work with: `"10"` is less than `"8.00"`.

I need to be able to validate against things like 8 and 8.75.  Is there a trick to get the max rule to play nice with non-integers, or another rule I should be using?

(As an aside, I will probably be updating to the latest version of the library at some point, so this question is just for what to do until I can make that change.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a trick to get the `max` rule to play nice with non-integers,

The `max` rule itself works fine... you're talking about an issue when declaring `max` using the `data-rule-max` attribute.  In that case, [updating the plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/fguxextv/2/) is your only solution.

> or another rule I should be using?

The `max` rule is the `max` rule.

If you can't update the plugin, then simply use the HTML 5 `max` attribute, instead of `data-rule-max`, to declare the `max` rule.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" max="8.00" />
```

**DEMO (v1.11.1):  http://jsfiddle.net/fguxextv/**

---

This is an issue of how the plugin maps the attributes over to available methods.  If mapping was not fixed within the plugin, you could simply declare the rule via the `.validate()` method.  In that case, it's `"max"`.

```
 $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        foo: {
            required: true,
            max: 8.00
        }, 
        ....
```

**DEMO 2 (v1.11.1):  http://jsfiddle.net/fguxextv/3/**

Comment: I'm glad it's that simple.  Our team's coding practice is to use data attributes all the time for consistency, but I think I can talk them into making this an exception until updating the library bubbles up the priority stack.  Thanks!